# Question about making a calendar but don't know how to fill date

Tags: excel, vba, calendar

I don't know how to fill in the calendar.
How do I code the starting point of each month is different? No matter what month I submit, I have to get the right starting date and ending date for that month.

The attached image is a calendar template and I need to fill in B4:H9.
[enter image description here][1]

Among the codes below, Q6, 7, and 8 are corresponding to what I want to do, but I don't know.

```
Sub CreateMonthlyCalendar(startDate As Date)
    'This Sub procedure is incomplete. For this assignment, you need to complete it
    'so that when a macro calls this Sub, given a starting date, the Sub will create
    'a calendar for the month and year of that starting date. For example, if the
    ' starting date is 1/1/2021, this Sub should create a calendar for January 2021.
    
    'These variables are given to help you get started. You can use them in this Sub.
       Dim stopDate As Date                           'stop date
       Dim yearNum As Integer                        'the year extracted from the start date
       Dim monName As String                        'the month name of the start date
       Dim numDaysMonth As Integer              'number of days in the month of the start date
       Dim weekdayNum As Integer                  'the week day number (Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.) of the start date
       Dim rngCalendar As Range                     'the rngCalendar contains cells that will be used
                                                                     'to represent the calendar
       Dim cell As Range                                   'a control cell variable used in the For Each loop
       Dim cellCounter As Integer                     'a running counter to count the number of cells that has
                                                                     'been processed so far in the rngCalendar
          
       '1. Given the satrtDate parameter above, you need to creates a calendar for the
       '   month and year of that starting date.
       '   To create this calendar, you need to determine other needed information
       '   from the starting date: stop date, year, month name, number of days in
       '   the given month, and weekday number.
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
       
stopDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(startDate, 0)
  

monName = MonthName(Month(startDate))
   
   
yearNum = Year(startDate)
   
      
numDaysMonth = stopDate - startDate + 1
   
           
weekdayNum = Weekday(startDate, vbMonday)
       
       
       
       
       '2. Create a copy of the "Template" sheet and place the copy at the end of the active workbook.
       '   Note: when you copy a worksheet, the newly created worksheet will
       '   automatically become the active worksheet
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
  
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(1)    
       
       '3. Rename the new "Template" sheet to the name of the month
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
        
Sheets("Template (2)").Name = monName

          
       '4. Assign the year extracted from the start date to cell E1
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
        
Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = yearNum

       
       '5. Assign the month name obtained from the start date to cell E2
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.

Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = monName      
          
       ****'6. Set the rngCalendar variable so that it will contain cells B4:H9
       '   of the active worksheet.
       '   This rngCalendar will be used to represent the calendar
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
          
       
       '7. You are now ready to process the cells in the rngCalendar. Initialize
       '   the cellCounter to 0. The cellCounter is a running counter to count
       '   the number of cells that has been processed so far in the rngCalendar
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
     
       
       '8. Use the For Each loop to process the cells in rngCalendar. You need to
       '   fill out the appropriate cells in rngCalendar so that it creates a
       '   calendar for the given starting date. For example, if the starting date
       '   is 05/01/2021, you need to create a calendar for May 2021.****
       'Note: You can assume that the For Each loop will process the cells from the
       '      top-left corner of a range and proceeds to the next cell on the right
       '      of the same row. When the first row has been processed, the For Each
       '      loop will process the next row from left to right until there is no
       '      more row to process.
       'Pseudocode:
       '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       'For each cell in the calendar template, do the following:
       '   increment cell counter, counting the number of cells that has been
       '      processed so far
       '   if the currently processed cell is for the first day of the month or after,
       '     mark this cell with an appropriate date
       '   otherwise,
       '     do nothing
       '   if we have processed enough cells to construct this monthly calendar,
       '     exit the loop
       '   repeat the process
       '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       
       '   Your code for this step starts below. You may create more lines as needed.
    
    
    
    
    End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR6X7.jpg
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150301/question-about-making-calendar-using-vba-i-should-make-the-calendar-but-i-don

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful to you.

```
Private Sub Scribble()

    Dim Dte     As Date
    
    Dte = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)        ' returns the first day of the current month
    Dte = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)        ' returns the last day of the previous month
    
    ' observe that the next line returns the last day of the month
    ' but the last one returns the same day a month prior.
    Dte = DateAdd("m", 1, Dte)                          ' adds one month to Dte
    Dte = DateAdd("m", -1, Dte)                         ' deducts one month from Dte
    
    ' another way to add a mmonth:-
    Dte = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)    ' returns the first day of the next month
    
    Debug.Print Dte
End Sub
```

Replace `Date` above with any valid date. In  that way you can calculate the first day of any month using the first formula. The last date of a month is always 1 day before the first day of the next month. Therefore `DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)) - 1` returns the last day of the current month.